# handling large queryset in django view to render it on webpage using streaminghttpresponse or some other alternative

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have written a view in django that queries a database and returns the output to requested page using django's `return render()`
But when the queryset have thousands of rows it takes alot of time for a webpage to give response and since i have also hosted this on heroku, by the time i get the response, heroku request timeout occurs.
Is there some way to send data in small chunks to the webpage continuously till all the data is received by the webpage.

view.py

```
...
queryset = Announcement.objects.filter(....)
context_data = {
...
"query_set":query_set,
...
}
return render(request,"index.html",context_data)
```

Expected result is that as soon as the request is made the requested page gets a response with partial result of queryset and incrementally continues to load all data.

Comment: paginate the queryset, also possible you can use django-channels

Comment: I think Django pagination us what you need: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/

Comment: pagination crossed my mind but for some reason i don't want to use it. i am thinking of something like streamingHttpResponse or exploiting the benefits of generator object. @JibinMathews

Comment: please refer above comment@SergeyPugach

Comment: Take a look at this : https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view